# Moodle create page with tutor contact details

Tags: moodle

The point to create Moodle tutor contact page. The **enrolled** student on the course when click on "Contact Tutor" from home page navigate to tutor page contacts, like email, mobile or/and moodle contact e.g. below
[Tutor contact page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHNm6.png)

The point how to make dynamically access different tutors details for different course students.

I tried show and hide pages permissions

Comment: There is a course contacts block you could download and install. You can set this to display teachers only.  https://moodle.org/plugins/block_course_contacts

Comment: Any ideas how to make without plugin?

Comment: Without plugin you could create a label zone and create the contacts but it'd be really fastidious... You could make your own plugin... Now : If your question isn't programming related, it goes against Stack Overflow guideline...